# Purchase Java part 2

Tags: java

Can any one help me? Our instructor said that he does'nt want to use array list in our program. And only array,for loops,and do while only.  The program is a Purchase program.(Adding item, records the transactions.) This is the first step i want to understand.

In this program, i want do display item code and descip properly. For example code=123 and descrip= yeah. The output displays, `Item code = 123, Item descrpition = yeah.` But once i say yes and i put another, example code =456 and desription = oh. Output `Item code = 123456, Item description = yeah.oh.`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Apps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        String code = "", des = "", ans;
        String[] b = new String[1];
        String[] aw = new String[1];
        int x;

        do {

            System.out.print("Item code:");
            code += "" + a.next();

            System.out.print("des:");
            des += "" + a.next();

            System.out.println("yes or no:");
            ans = a.next();

        }

        while (ans.equals("yes"));

        for (x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
            b[x] = code;
            aw[x] = des;

            System.out.println("Item code:" + b[x]);
            System.out.println("Item description:" + aw[x]);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This code might cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @nikpon that's what my instructor wants. infinite with no fix value.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel what do you mean sir?

Comment: Use the debugger to see what exactly happens.

Comment: Can you ask how many items you want in advance?  You are setting your array length to 1, so you won't be able to store more than 1 thing at a time (that is if you even stored it in the array to begin with).  If you aren't able to ask how many up front, you may have to dynamically resize your array to fit what the user wants (maybe that is the point of the assignment?)

Comment: @Raymond: Look at the edit made by Grantham. It's a lot easier to read code if it's indented properly.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia the idea is like a purchase prog for example. the user must able to save the item including- price,qty,desc. That's what our assignment is all about.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel where can i find it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for any number of items. It stores data in String and splits the string after user selects no.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ans;
    String itemCounts = "";
    String descriptions = "";

    do {
        System.out.print("Item code:");
        itemCounts += "" + a.next() + "\n";

        System.out.print("des:");
        descriptions += "" + a.next() + "\n";

        System.out.println("yes or no:");
        ans = a.next();
    } while (ans.equals("yes"));

    String[] b = itemCounts.split("\n");
    String[] aw = descriptions.split("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Item code:" + b[i]);
        System.out.println("Item description:" + aw[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the use of split?

Comment: It splits string with the given expression.

Comment: ah. i see. that's how it works. by the way, can i incorporate this answer to hide the details. and displays only once i enter the right code.

Comment: @Raymond...this program works fine, but I doubt you instructor will accept usage of java provided String methods (split in this case). He wants you to do some more logic building :)

Answer (score 0):

[`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) **doesn't** handle the end of the line, so when you call `next()` again, it'll take as input the enter (`\n`) you entered before.

You should call `nextLine()` after each `next()` (So it will swallow the `\n` from the previous one).

Comment: what can be the output for that sir?

Comment: how will i elaborate this? basically this codes that i used is to simply display my item code and description. but my problem is that once i repeat to input a detail - code & description. it only connects the past details. and don't separate to the previous inputs

Answer (score 0):

This works for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ans;
    int capacity = 100;
    String[] b = new String[capacity];
    String[] aw = new String[capacity];
    int itemCount = 0;
    int x;

    do {           
        System.out.print("Item code:");
        b[itemCount] =  a.next();

        System.out.print("des:");
        aw[itemCount] = a.next();

        System.out.println("yes or no:");
        ans = a.next();
         itemCount++;
    } while (ans.equals("yes"));

    for (x = 0; x < itemCount; x++) {
        System.out.println("Item code:" + b[x]);
        System.out.println("Item description:" + aw[x]);
    }
}
```

If you want to be sure, that user can add "infinite" numbers of items, you have to manualy check if the itemCount is lesser than capacity of array and when it reaches, you have to allocate new array with higher capacity and copy the values into it.

Comment: it can be. but he said that the element inside the array must not be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve this using collections like :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Apps
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ans;

    ArrayList<String> br = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Item code:");
        br.add(a.next());

        System.out.print("des:");
        ar.add(a.next());

        System.out.println("yes or no:");
        ans = a.next();

    }

    while (ans.equals("yes"));

    for (int i = 0; i < br.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Item code:" + br.get(i));
        System.out.println("Item description:" + ar.get(i));
    }

    }

}
```

But not sure if can be achieved with array, or

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
    String code = "", des = "", ans;
    int capacity = 100;
    String[] b = new String[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    String[] aw = new String[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
    int itemCount = 0;
    int x;

    do {           
        System.out.print("Item code:");
        b[itemCount] =  a.next();

        System.out.print("des:");
        aw[itemCount] = a.next();

        System.out.println("yes or no:");
        ans = a.next();
         itemCount++;
    } while (ans.equals("yes"));

    for (x = 0; x < itemCount; x++) {
        System.out.println("Item code:" + b[x]);
        System.out.println("Item description:" + aw[x]);
    }

}
```

Interger.MAX_VALUE is the number of times you can run this but not infinite, because array size has to be defined at compile time.

Comment: the problem is that our instructor does'nt want to put array list.

Comment: i tried to use array list. and it's possible. however, ours intructor wants it to be in array only.

Comment: then you can run till Integer.MAX_VALUE :(